# How do I remove columns of a dataframe based on the values of other dataframes?

Tags: r

If >50% of the subjects in BOTH groups (`p0` and `p1`) have a p-value >.05, I want to remove the exon probe (columns) from the `e` dataframe.

My attempt:

```
# If >50% of the subjects in BOTH groups have a p-value >.05, remove this exon probe.
e <- if (e[rowMeans(p0 < 0.05) > 0.5,]) {
  if (e[rowMeans(p1 < 0.05) > 0.5,]) {
    return(e)
  }
}
```

Traceback:

> Error in if (e[rowMeans(p0 < 0.05) > 0.5, ]) { :   argument is not
> interpretable as logical In addition: Warning message: In if
> (e[rowMeans(p0 < 0.05) > 0.5, ]) { :   the condition has length > 1
> and only the first element will be used

```
e=structure(list(JHU_113_2.CEL = c(4.21222, 1.46773, 6.28274, 4.27911,
5.81678), JHU_144.CEL = c(4.24054, 1.6898, 6.79161, 3.53146,
5.71165), JHU_173.CEL = c(3.55855, 1.54697, 6.11265, 3.83499,
6.02794), JHU_176R.CEL = c(4.57541, 1.75198, 6.13997, 3.71238,
5.37082), JHU_182.CEL = c(4.50411, 1.35377, 6.68056, 3.38309,
5.95527)), row.names = c(2315252L, 2315253L, 2315374L, 2315375L,
2315376L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
p0=structure(list(JHU_144.CEL = c(0.04224, 0.38068, 0.00293, 0.29977,
0.01525), JHU_186.CEL = c(0.03532, 0.28369, 0.00788, 0.10076,
0.03559), JHU_205.CEL = c(0.21461, 0.97292, 0.0672, 0.01755,
0.05689), JHU_210.CEL = c(0.36106, 0.33458, 0.00116, 0.07026,
0.11264), JHU_211R3.CEL = c(0.1347, 0.64219, 0.00873, 0.24551,
0.02603)), row.names = c(2315252L, 2315253L, 2315374L, 2315375L,
2315376L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
p1=structure(list(JHU_113_2.CEL = c(0.09655, 0.64864, 0.0073, 0.11744,
0.04079), JHU_173.CEL = c(0.22314, 0.49589, 0.03034, 0.21102,
0.0309), JHU_176R.CEL = c(0.03202, 0.38359, 0.02571, 0.21728,
0.08493), JHU_182.CEL = c(0.03889, 0.9356, 0.00436, 0.33313,
0.01303), JHU_187.CEL = c(0.06716, 0.39982, 0.0052, 0.32012,
0.02163)), row.names = c(2315252L, 2315253L, 2315374L, 2315375L,
2315376L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the answer.

```
cols_to_delete <- c()

for(i in 1:dim(p0)[2]){
    #If you sum over T/F values in R, it returns the total number true
    numLessp0 <- sum(p0[i] > 0.05)
    numLessp1 <- sum(p1[i] > 0.05)

    #Take the number of successes and divide by the total number to get percentages
    if(numLessp0/length(p0[i]) > 0.5 | numLessp1/length(p1[i]) > 0.5){
    #Do nothing
    } else { #Mark column for deletion
    cols_to_delete <- c(cols_to_delete, i)
    }
}

e <- subset(e,select = -cols_to_delete)
```

Edit: I think I misunderstood your question a bit. I fixed the code and reposted it

Edit2: I think I made a mistake again. Let me try yet again

```
cols_to_delete <- c()

for(col in colnames(e)){
#Check if the column is in both p dataframes
  isinp0 <- col %in% colnames(p0)
  isinp1 <- col %in% colnames(p1)

  #If it is not in the dataframe, then return false for the check. Otherwise, conduct the check and return its value
#If you sum over T/F values in R, it returns the total number true
#Take the number of successes and divide by the total number to get percentages
   isvalidp0 <- ifelse(!isinp0,F,sum(p0[col] < 0.05)/length(p0) > 0.5)

   isvalidp1 <- ifelse(!isinp1,F,sum(p1[col] < 0.05)/length(p1) > 0.5)
       
    if(isvalidp0 | isvalidp1){
    #Do nothing
    } else { #Mark column for deletion
    cols_to_delete <- c(cols_to_delete, col)
    }
}

#Select only those columns that do not need to be deleted
e <- e[!colnames(e) %in% cols_to_delete]
```

Comment: The code returns `NULL` and did not change the dimensions of `e`.

Comment: I  just redid the code. I misunderstood your question initially because I didn't pay enough attention to the dataframes you were talking about :P

Comment: Wait, your column names aren't the same. What do you want to do in that scenario?

Comment: Which column names are not the same? Did you mean the JHU_113.CEL etc? The dataframes are basically a subset of the original dataframes so that's why it's different.

Comment: For example, e has a JHU_113.2.CEL but p0 does not, as far as I can tell. I am guessing you would just want to check in p1 in that case, but I want to make sure

Comment: p0 and p1 is subsetted from an original df `p`.

Comment: Error in -cols_to_delete: invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: I think the version I just posted should work. Sorry about messing it up at first

Comment: `cols_to_delete` returns NULL and there's still no change to the `e` dataframe.

Comment: To be more precise, `p0` and `p1` are subsets of `p` dataframe based on class memberships (0,1) so they are mutually exclusive. They are the p-values.

Comment: I just ran it on my computer and it worked. I am left with only two columns left: JHU_144.CEL and JHU_182.CEL. Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241683/discussion-between-melolili-and-user3124634).